# Can I create a subscription that notifies only those context attributes that has changed?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Is there any way to create a subscription in [Orion Context Broker](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to notify any changes in the context, but only notify those attributes that have changed?

At the moment, the only way I found to do this is to create several subscriptions, each one pointing to changes in a certain attribute of the context and notifying only that attribute (similar to what is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48517191/7993163)). The problem is that this solution is not maintainable in practice because you need to create as many subscriptions as attributes in the context.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes to include in notifications are controlled by the `attrs` or `exceptAttrs` fields in `notification` (see [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable) for details). Thus, current options are "all attributes", "all attributes except a fixed list" or "a fixes list of attributes".

However, note [this issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3190) in Orion repository. I think is exactly what you mean. Feel free adding comments to that issue or stating your support to it.

**EDIT:** A workaround would be to use `previousValue` metadata. Thus, you can subscribe for all attributes (using `"attrs": [ ]` or omitting the field) including `previousValue` metadata in notifications (using `"metadata": [ "previousValue" ]`). So, your notifications receiver knows if an attribute has actually changed, just comparing the value of the attribute and the value of the `previousValue` metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @fgalan !! The [feature](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3190) that you posted in the Github repo would be the perfect solution for this problem. I will be waiting for any news about it!!

Comment: About the workaround that you mention, it's quite ingenious but I'm not sure if I can configure for example [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus) to do it (as I mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3190)). On the contrary, I intuit that it is something that I can only do by adding some lines of code in the middle between Orion and Cygnus.

Comment: You are right, Cygnus doesn't process the `previousValue` metadata. Your man-in-the-middle approach will work, although would add some complexity.

Comment: However, in the case of Perseo CEP, given that you can use metadata in EPL rule predicates it would be possible to use `previousValue` in rules (at least in theory).